# registering JavaScriptSerializer with signalr

Tags: model-view-controller, signalr, javascriptserializer

can we use JavaScriptSerializer as default serializer of signalr. if so how we'll register to signalr.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Although there's a pluggable interface SignalR is tied to JSON.NET